# SSH connection not established, but standard TCP/IP connection works

Tags: linux, ssh, wireshark, pcap

I'm working on a custom yocto Linux for a Raspberry PI 3 and try to get the WIFI connection working with SSH. However when trying to connect from my PC (Ubuntu 19.10, SSH OpenSSH_8.0p1 Ubuntu-6build1, OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019) to the PI on which Dropbear v2019.78 runs, the connection attempt times out. But only when I try this via SSH, and via `wlan0`. Other TCP/IP traffic works, and also using the same participants but with `eth0`. As this is for a robot, I would prefer to not use a tether though...

To try & debug this, I

- enabled a serial console so I can work on the PI
- disabled eth0
- started a tcpdump on the PI (ip.host == 192.168.0.105)
- started a tcpdump on the PC (ip.host == 192.168.0.106)
- used a dirt-simple TCP/IP socket example written in Python (taken from https://realpython.com/python-sockets/#echo-server) to verify I can in fact communicate. The transmission is successful. I am aware that the example is lacking (no proper protocol etc), but that's not the point of it. It just works enough. The PI runs the server listening on port 2222.
- attempted a SSH connection, it timed out.

I filtered the resulting PCAP down to contain just TCP, as there is other information (e.g. Dropbox discovery) that I don't think matters and might potentially be information leaking. On the host side (enp4s0-tcp-and-pi.pcap) I also filtered with `ip.host == 192.168.0.105` to only contain any traffic to the PI.

Another note on my setup here: I use a TP-Link router which LAN ports the PC is connected to, and who provides the 2.4GHz WIFI for the PI. So both are part of the same subnet, and no special routing or anything is configured.

Also I stopped the dropbear daemon and adapted my Python code to use port 22. It works.

I'm only broadly aware of the inner workings of TCP, so I can't really make much sense of the things I see here. Any insights are more than welcome.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5o4rqr5zdws2wq7/wlan0-tcp-only.pcap?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/amypjtk1nvja4qb/enp4s0-tcp-and-pi.pcap?dl=0

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this is off-topic for Stack Overflow as it does not pertain to programming. You should ask this on Server Fault instead.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion. I did search and found things like wireshark etc, thus I thought this is appropriate. But I'll try and move this elsewhere.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/1015560/ssh-connection-not-established-but-standard-tcp-ip-connection-works

Comment: When in doubt, check documentation. This is Stack Overflow’s on-topic [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). It’s a detailed question, so points for that.